# vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/DefinitionAggregator.php on line 91

Tags: magento2.3.5

I installed import and export plugin and got this error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: version in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/DefinitionAggregator.php on line 91
```

Magento 2.3.5
PHP 7.3

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Restart your MySQL server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

then try again. If you still see this error, you might have to re-install your MySQL server